# import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth"; to expo project causes problem only in ios

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, react-native-firebase

I get this error message

`Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist.

If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info., js engine: hermes`

and in the emulater shows :-

```
constructor (nativeModule: ?NativeModule) {
45 | if (Platform.OS == 'ios' {
> 46 |
invariant (
47 |
48
49
nativeModule ! = null,
'new NativeEventEmitter()' requires a non
NativeEventEmitter.js (46:16)
```

when I try to import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth"; to expo project I just followed all steps to use react-native-firebase in both Expo website and react-native-firebase website but I still have same problem.

I try to use react-native-firebase in expo project